# How to set item checked in listview1 when doubleclick on the same item on other listview2

Tags: vb.net, listview

I have two listviews with products list in two diferent forms.
I need to make: 
When I doubleclick on product in listview1 I need to set checked property on same item in listview2:

[image]

Comment: Since you're using the DoubleClick event (so just one item is selected), you can get the current Item with `dim Item = listView1.SelectedItems(0)` and set `listView2.Items(Item.Index).Checked = Not listView2.Items(Item.Index).Checked`. You can also get the items clicked with the Hit test: `dim Item = listView1.HitTest(listView1.PointToClient(Cursor.Position)).Item`

Comment: (check whether there are actually items in the Listview before anything). If you use the `MouseDoubleClick` event, you already have the Position translated (in case you're interested).

Comment: You can also use the `ListView.FindItemWithText()` method to locate an Item with the same text as the one selected.

Comment: ListView2.Items(Item.Index).Checked = Not Me.ListView1.Items(Item.Index).Checked


This code work fine if number of items in both listview are the same. But didn't work if some items missing in second listview. How I can on doubleclick on first listview, find ID and then select item with the same ID in the second listview ?

Answer (score 1):

This code with [`ListView.FindItemWithText()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listview.finditemwithtext) method works fine for me.

```
Private Sub ListView1_SelectedDoubleClick(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles ListView1.DoubleClick
    Dim Item = ListView2.FindItemWithText(ListView1.SelectedItems(0).Text)
    If Item IsNot Nothing Then
        Item.Checked = Not Item.Checked
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: You can accept your own answer after a bit of time. This will show you question as answered and show other users that the problem was solved.